# PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR:Password command failed: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid

Tags: php, aws, phpmailer

He utilizado la libreria phpmailer() para enviar correo a los usuarios desde mi servidor en AWS usando el script php, pero no puedo enviar a pesar de que todo está bien en mi script de acuerdo con el código phpmailer.
Mi código es este:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$sender = 'sender@example.com';
$senderName = 'Sender Name';

$recipient = 'recipient@example.com';

$usernameSmtp = 'smtp_username';

$passwordSmtp = 'smtp_password';

$host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
$port = 587;

$subject = 'Testing Email';

$bodyText =  'Probando';

$bodyHtml = 'Funciona';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $senderName);
    $mail->Username   = $usernameSmtp;
    $mail->Password   = $passwordSmtp;
    $mail->Host       = $host;
    $mail->Port       = $port;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', $configurationSet);

    
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body       = $bodyHtml;
    $mail->AltBody    = $bodyText;
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Email sent!" , PHP_EOL;
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo "An error occurred. {$e->errorMessage()}", PHP_EOL; //Catch errors from PHPMailer.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Email not sent. {$mail->ErrorInfo}", PHP_EOL; //Catch errors from Amazon SES.
}
?>
```

**Nota:** El correo del cual se van a enviar los mensajes es Outlook, el cual ya esta autenticado en Amazon SES y también cree las credenciales SMTP y se las asigne a las variables en el código.

**El error que arroja es:**

```
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO api.ferreteriasamir.com
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO api.ferreteriasamir.com
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-01-19 20:23:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-01-19 20:23:49 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Authentication Credentials Invalid
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-01-19 20:23:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Email not sent. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Le agradezco de antemano si alguien me puede ayudar, Gracias!

Comment: Primero prueba tus credenciales SMTP aca https://www.smtper.net/ y verifica que te da true antes de ir a Código

Comment: Ese error casi siempre es por el puerto, juega con eso,el 587 por el 465 o viceversa, pero prueba en smtper y nos comentas

Comment: Parece que es un problema más complicado, como que Amazon no deja enviar correos así por así con el usuario y contraseña. Revisa [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47128467/1545868) y [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558463/1545868) (en inglés). También revisar [Amazon SES SMTP interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/smtp-credentials.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, voy a probar todo

Comment: He intentado hacer todo lo que me han recomendado pero lastimosamente nada me ha funcionado